# Backbone Marionette CompositeViews show extra div tags

Tags: marionette

I'm trying to render a Bootstrap Navigation list using CompositeView and ItemView. The html I need to generate is something like

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="nav-header">List header</li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

To do this I have 3 backbone views -

```
<script type="text/html" id="vw-search-facets">
    <h4>Filter By</h4>
    <ul class="nav nav-list">

    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="vw-search-facet-group">
    <li class="nav-header"><%= name %></li>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="vw-search-facet">
    <a href="#" id="<%= value %>"><%= name %> (<%= count %>)</a>
</script>
```

vw-search-facets and vw-search-facet-group are CompositeViews, vw-search-facet is an ItemView.

However, when this is rendered I get extra divs around the vw-search-facet-group view

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
<div>        
    <li class="nav-header">City</li>
    <li><a href="#" id="Athens">Athens (9)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="Jackson">Jackson (2)</a></li>
</div>
</ul>
```

I can understand that this is happening because the vw-search-facet-group view needs a container within which to render and so by default creates a div, however this is undesirable.

How can I change this to remove those extra divs?

Thanks

**Update** View Definitions

```
Reservations.SearchFacetView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    model: Reservations.SearchFacet,
    template: '#vw-search-facet',
    tagName: 'li'
});

Reservations.SearchFacetGroupView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#vw-search-facet-group",
    itemView: Reservations.SearchFacetView
});

Reservations.SearchFacetsListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    itemView: Reservations.SearchFacetGroupView,
    itemViewContainer: "ul.nav-list",
    template: "#vw-search-facets"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I went down another route with this. Instead of making the parent composite view contain the ul, I changed it to a simple div and then made each child use a ul as its container.

```
<script type="text/html" id="vw-search-facets">
<h4>Filter By</h4>
<div id="facet-list">

</div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="vw-search-facet-group">
    <li class="nav-header"><%= name %></li>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="vw-search-facet">
    <a href="#" id="<%= value %>"><%= name %> (<%= count %>)</a>
</script>
```

And the updated view definitions

```
Reservations.SearchFacetView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    model: Reservations.SearchFacet,
    template: '#vw-search-facet',
    tagName: 'li'
});

Reservations.SearchFacetGroupView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#vw-search-facet-group",
    itemView: Reservations.SearchFacetView,
    tagName: 'ul',
    initialize: function () {
        this.$el.addClass("nav").addClass("nav-list");
    },
});

Reservations.SearchFacetsListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    itemView: Reservations.SearchFacetGroupView,
    itemViewContainer: "#facet-list",
    template: "#vw-search-facets"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Thanks for posting the views.  I see the shape of what you are trying to do.  I am not sure that your approach would work with multiple facet groups without defining a custom AppendHtml method to add item views the the inner composite view.

```
Reservations.SearchFacetGroupView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#vw-search-facet-group",
    itemView: Reservations.SearchFacetView,
    appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index){
      collectionView.$("li").last().after(itemView.el);
    }
});
```

Have you tested this with more than one facet group yet?

Also, is there a strong case for using a single ul with multiple headings?  It would be much easier to build this with a separate ul for each group.

Comment: Thanks, but won't that wrap the li around all the sub-items too? So I would end up with 

<ul class="nav nav-list">
<li class="nav-header">City
    <li><a href="#" id="Athens">Athens (9)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="Jackson">Jackson (2)</a></li>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: Can you post your view definitions?